# How I can call the output in the refcursor using Stored procedure in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to output in refcursor but it's not working.

I tried a lot of thing to get output in refcursor and sometimess its showing <Unnamed Portal 1>

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MasterUser".s_m_userapplication(
    v_app_no text,
    INOUT v_refcur refcursor DEFAULT 'rs_resultone'::refcursor)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
   open v_refcur for select AM_App_ProcCD,AM_App_ProcDt
   from "MasterUser".Master_Application
   where "MasterUser".appnov1(CAST(AM_AAPP_NO_TYPE AS INTEGER), AM_AAPP_NO_YEAR, AM_AAPP_NO_MONTH, AM_AAPP_NO_SEQ) =(v_App_No);
END;
 
 
 
$BODY$;

ALTER PROCEDURE "MasterUser".s_m_userapplication(text, refcursor)
    OWNER TO USERDBA;
```

Comment: Use a function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using INOUT `refcursor` you will be viewing always one column and one record using the call my_procedure(). Inside the column value you can view your selecting records. (See picture) If you're getting data from the cursor on the backend, you don't care about the IDE view. On the backend side this will work. If you need to view data like as `select * from table` then you must use function instead of procedure.

[image]

Comment: Sir which IDE you are using for postgresql??

Comment: @JohnCarter -  DBeaver (support all databases), best IDE, open source and free.

Comment: we have migrated oracle database to PostgreSQL and That all Stored Procedure are converted into functions so, can we use transactions in Function??

Comment: On PostgreSQL inside the function, you can not use `start tran` or `commit tran`, but one function = one transaction, begin = `start transaction`, end  = `commit transaction`, you can split transactions within a procedure into multi functions. If an exception occurs inside the function, then the whole function goes to the rollback process. It's best to read the documentation about it, as there are various some details.